# Keyboard Layout settings do not survive reboot

Tags: keyboard-layout

I'm on Xubuntu 12.04. I use Hebrew as well as English US.

When I installed Xubuntu I added Hebrew via the Keyboard Layout settings and set ALT-SHIFT as the change layout shortcut. In both cases when I've installed Xubuntu, this worked well and no issues.

After everything worked fine on this laptop, it all of a sudden started to misbehave. Every time I restart, the Keyboard Layout settings revert to only US and the change layout shortcut is forgotten. I re-add the language and update the change layout shortcut and it forgets it again after reboot.

I don't believe I've changed anything, but I must have (or an update caused it?).

Where is the keyboard layout configuration saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your keyboard layout settings using **dconf-editor**. Start it from Dash, navigate to `org →  gnome → libgnomekbd → keyboard` and select the `layout` key. Here is my dconf window:

[image: dconf window]

As you can see, I use *Russian* layout along with *English*. Also, `options` key holds switching combination. I suppose you should set these keys to ['us', 'il'] and ['grp\tgrp:lalt_lshift_toggle'] correspondingly.

Comment: Looks like this solved it!

Comment: Now it started happening again! I did an update of Ubuntu, maybe it overruns it?

Comment: Yes, may be. Do settings in Keyboard Layout survive reboot now?

Comment: Yes. Very annoying behavior

Comment: I am not sure it's related, but consider tracking this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1218322